# FileNotFoundError: subprocess.Popen(['dir'] (Windows 7)

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm playing around with `subprocess.Popen` for shell commands as it seems it has more flexbility with regards to piping compared to `subprocess.run`

I'm starting off with some simple examples but I'm getting `FileNotFoundError:`

I was told that `shell = True` is not necessary if I make the arguments as proper lists. However it doesn't seem to be working.

Here are my attempts:

```
import subprocess
p1 =subprocess.Popen(['dir'], stdout =subprocess.PIPE)

output = p1.communicate[0]


p = subprocess.Popen([ "dir", "c:\\Users"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
outputs = p.communicate()
```

Both are leading to `FileNotFoundError`

Comment: `dir` is not an executable, its a shell command

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As `dir` is simply a command understood by `cmd.exe` (or `powershell.exe`) then you could:

```
subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "/c", "dir", "c:\\Users"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

which corresponds to doing the following in a shell

```
C:\>cmd /c dir c:\Users
```

You may find you have to fully path `cmd`, as `c:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe`

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about `/c` flag.  Is there a way to have the shell stay open after execution. I tried using '/k' as a flag, instead of '/c' but the shell is still closing.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that "dir" is an internal Windows command and your "popen" is looking for the name of an executable.  You could try setting up a "dir.bat" file that runs the "dir" command to see if this works or simply try any of the commands in \Windows\system32 instead.

Answer (score -2):

Try this (on windows):

```
import subprocess

file_name = "test.txt"

sp = subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "/c", 'dir', '/s', '/p', file_name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output = sp.communicate()
output = output[1].decode()

if file_name in output:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

On Linux, replace the call to subprocess like this:

```
sp = subprocess.Popen(['find', '-name', file_name, '/'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I htink the key is in: `stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE`