# subprocess.call() in windows 10 returns an error that it can't find the file

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am working on a unix script that needs some adaptations to work under windows 10. The script uses subprocess to perform file operations using DOS commands. Specifically, a statement that uses subprocess to copy a file from a directory to the current directory returns an error message.
The correct DOS command is

```
copy "D:\tess\catalog files\TIC55234031.fts" .
```

However,

```
ref_fits_filename="D:\TESS\catalog files\TIC55234031.fts"
```

and

```
subprocess.call(['copy ', ref_fits_filename,' .'])         # copy the ref fits file to here
```

which aims to perform exactly the same operation, goes wrong:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "EBcheck.py", line 390, in 
    subprocess.call(['copy ', ref_fits_filename,' .'])         # copy the ref fits file to here
  File "C:\Users\FD-Computers\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 267, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Users\FD-Computers\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\FD-Computers\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Obviously, there must be a subtle syntax error or an issue I haven't though of that causes the problem.
Are there experts in Python programmming under windows 10 to clarify the issue on this forum ?
The Python version used here is the recent Python 3.6.4.

Comment: `copy` is shell-builtin. You'd need `shell=True` for this. plus there's a space in your copy arg.

Answer (score 4):

Many reasons for this:

1. `copy` is a Windows shell builtin, it's not an executable. You'd have to use `shell=True`
2. your `subprocess.call(['copy ', ref_fits_filename,' .'])` has spaces in the arguments

So you *could* do:

```
subprocess.call(['copy', ref_fits_filename,'.'],shell=True)
```

But the most pythonic way would be to drop all this and use `shutil.copy`

```
import shutil
shutil.copy(ref_fits_filename,".")
```

As a bonus, if the copy goes wrong, you get a clean python exception.

Aside: always use raw prefix when defining windows paths as literals:

```
ref_fits_filename = r"D:\tess\catalog files\TIC55234031.fts"
```

(I guess you uppercased `tess` to `TESS` to workaround the fact that `\t` is the tabulation char :))

Comment: is `r"C:\Some Path With Space\myfile.txt"` enough to work with spacefilled paths our would one neet do do  `r'"C:\Some Path With Space\myfile.txt"'` ?

Comment: the space isn't the issue here. The issue is escape sequences like `\t`, `\n`, which explains why unaware windows users have a tendency to uppercase all paths (it fails with `\U` though)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this is a problem with win10 and older versions. I tested a code with win11, and it worked as it should. However, on a virtual machine with win10, it failed and that is the reason I found this question/solution and others on the internet.

Although `shell = True` works, it is not a good idea. To avoid `shell = True`, use the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49018413/filenotfounderror-subprocess-popendir-windows-7):

`subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "/c", "dir", "c:\\Users"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`